# Bundling workflow in expo react-native

Tags: react-native, babeljs, expo

What are the steps of the bundling/packaging process? I know there are expo-cli, babel, metro... but do not get how they call each other to produce the final javascript bundle.

Any ideas or direction?

P/S: in a specific case, I want to ignore some files from being bundled, but do not know where to config this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for anyone who may need this...

The flow is `expo-cli` call the `react-native`'s `local-cli` at (node_modules\react-native\local-cli), which will transform the code with `babel` and package them with `metro`. `expo-cli` also pass packager options likes `packagerOpts` to `react-native`.

Also this article is helpful to understand `babel`: https://kleopetrov.me/2016/03/18/everything-about-babel/

In my specific case, I modify `app.json` like this:

```
...
"packagerOpts": {
  "assetExts": ["ttf", "tkon"]
},
"assetBundlePatterns": ["./app/config/*.tkon"]
...
```

which tells the packager that all files with `.tkon` extension is asset. They will be exclude from the final JS bundle, and can be required as asset.

Later I load this asset with:

```
let asset = Asset.fromModule(require('../../config/products.tkon'));
await asset.downloadAsync();
let data = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(asset.localUri);
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

That's it